# How to calculate the "triangle" for stirling numbers as fast as possible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

In an exam, I had to calculate the stirling number of second kind $S_{8,6}$. We were given the hint to calculate the "triangle" for stirling numbers of second kind for n = 8 (talking about this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Table_of_values). This seems like quite an effort though. How would I go about this if I want to calculate it as fast as possible? Some cases seem obvious of course, but most of then can't be calculated by intuition.

Comment: Just calculate the entries "above" the entry you care about.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Calculating some of them still seems pretty hard, for example for $n = 7$ and $k = 5$.

Comment: Look at that table. You only need to calculate the main diagonal (all $1$), the diagonal below that up to $S(7,6)$ (easy: triangular numbers) and then the diagonal below that up to $S(8,6)$. That requires a little work.

Comment: @Julian: ... and to calculate $S(7,5)$, just calculate the entries "above" it.

Comment: But how do I calculate them? The patterns for the first and second diagonal are easy to see, but for the third diagonal (the one where S(8,6) appears), it gets much harder. There must be some quick way to do it, but I don't see it.

Comment: I guess I need the formula $S(n,k) = S(n-1, k-1) + kS(n-1, k)$?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the row $n=0$, which is totally null for all values of column index $m$ (including $m=-1$) , except for $m=0$ which is $1$,
then the triangle canbe easily calculated with the recursion
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  n \cr 
  m \cr}  \right\} = m\left\{ \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  m \cr}  \right\} + \left\{ \matrix{
  n - 1 \cr 
  m - 1 \cr}  \right\}
$$

Otherwise the Stirling Numbers of 2nd kind can be directly calculated by the sum
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  n \cr 
  m \cr}  \right\}\quad  = {1 \over {m!}}\sum\limits_j {\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)j^{\,n} \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,m - j} }  = {1 \over {m!}}\sum\limits_j {\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( {m - j} \right)^{\,n} \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} } 
$$